# Android Studio New Project Template Uses Plugins not Dependencies

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle

How do I add safeargs and secrets as a plugin, or must it remain as dependency?

The latest Kotlin template for new fragment + view model build.gradle(Project) uses plugins {} not dependencies {}
Here is my work around, how do convert a classpath with path:plugin:version plugin id.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        // not compatible with upgraded gradle classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0"
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857476/unable-to-load-class-androidcomponentsextension-after-upgrading-the-android-grad/70857477
        // Update this line to use 2.5.0-alpha01
        // While Navigation 2.4.1 is not out yet
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0-alpha01"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
    }
}
// buildscript MUST come before this these are used in the project build.gradle not a dependency
/* This came with the 'new project template' replaced with old style dependencies,
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
} */
```

The build.gradle for the module, is different, no version, so easy to convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these repositories in `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

One can replace the `buildscript` block with:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.0-alpha02' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.0' apply false
}
```

Maybe with or without that `-gradle-plugin` suffix.

Comment: This works for a new project. However my upgrade attempt on an existing project did not work. I did not discover what additional changes are required, but this solution answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: @ShimonRothschild The `buildscript` block may be conflicting; if one can migrate to `pluginManagement` depends on the plugins and plugin repositories used; in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135974/549372) I've explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `repositories` block to the `buildscript` in the project level `build.gradle` file.
It should be in the project `settings.gradle` file.

Here's my work around:

- `build.gradle(Project)`

  ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
  buildscript {

   dependencies {

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
       classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
       classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0-alpha02"
   }
  }

  plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
  ```
- `settings.gradle(Project Settings)` The repositories are declared here.

  ```
  pluginManagement {
   repositories {
       gradlePluginPortal()
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
  }
  dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
  }

  rootProject.name = "Dictionary App"
  include ':app'
  ```

Comment: Thank you, this might work in some scenarios, but my objective was to replace all classpath dependencies with plugin id. One important point you make is that order matters, pluginManagement needs to be before dependencyResolutionManagement.